# Changing cloud project status from Testing to Production

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I recently created a Google Cloud project for the sole purpose of getting client credentials to use for sending OAUTH2 emails via gmail servers. I send them using a custom C# email app I developed for personal use only. There is no web page for this app since it is not and never will be available to the public.

Is it possible to get my Google Cloud project's status changed from "Testing" to "Production" without creating some kind of needless website for my email project? I have two other similar Cloud projects that were created over the last few years in order to get similar OAUTH2 client credentials and I was able to get their status's changed to "Production" without the need for a home page, but I don't remember how I did it.

Obviously I know very little about this process so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why was there a vote to close this question?

Comment: Review this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and make sure your question is on-topic. For me, you often need to know how to configure the service in order to write software. Another possible reason is that you did not show what you tried and errors or warnings. If Google reports `required` there is little that we can do to change that requirement.